# Mongodb: query to filter by filed in array of deeply nested documents

Tags: mongodb

I have this data structure:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "fieldToFilterBy": "1",
      "child": {
        "fieldToFilterBy": "2",
        "child": {
          "fieldToFilterBy": "3"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "fieldToFilterBy": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

*categories* is an array of unknown length. Each entry in *categories* is tree, where parent has only one or zero *child*. This “entries” can have different height.

**Problem:**

I need to filter all documents that have specific value of fieldToFilterBy.

**What I tried:**

1. `{ $or: [{ "categories.fieldToFilterBy": "1"}, {"categories.child.fieldToFilterBy" : "1" }]}` , but this hardly an option, because the exact height is unknown.
2. Create new field in document that contains list of fieldToFilterBy:

> ```
> {
>   "categories": [],
>   "fieldsToFilterBy": [
>     {
>       "fields": ["1", "2", "3"]
>     },
>     {
>       "fields": ["5"]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

this one doesn’t fit, because I don’t want to clutter document with fields that have no business value.

**Is there a clean way to achieve that kind of filtering?**

Comment: Got answer here
https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-to-filter-by-filed-in-array-of-deeply-nested-documents/113347
see Rafael_Green's response, he suggests splitting data between two collections

Comment: Another answers by John_Page contain interesting recommendations and new solution to my use-case
https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/query-to-filter-by-filed-in-array-of-deeply-nested-documents/113347